# C# Flag get values of combination flag

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have an *enum* with `[Flags]` attribute, e.g.

```
[Flags]
public enum PhoneService
{
   None = 0,
   LandLine = 1,
   Cell = 2,
   Fax = 4,
   Internet = 8,
   All = LandLine | Cell | Fax | Internet
}

// Should print "LandLine, Cell, Fax, Internet"
Console.WriteLine(PhoneService.All);
```

How to get all the underlying values in the combination flag `All`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you have names for *bits* within `enum` you can try something like this:

```
using System.Reflection;

...

public static string NameToBits<T>(T value) where T : Enum {
  // If not marked with `Flags` return name without splitting into bits
  if (typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(FlagsAttribute)) == null)
    return Enum.GetName(typeof(T), value);

  IEnumerable<string> Names() {
    ulong data = Convert.ToUInt64(value);

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
      if ((data & (1ul << i)) != 0)
        yield return Enum.GetName(typeof(T), 1ul << i);
  }

  return string.Join(", ", Names());
}
```

Demo:

```
public enum PhoneService {
  None = 0,

  LandLine = 1,
  Cell = 2,
  Fax = 4,
  Internet = 8,

  // Let's have more combinations
  Offline = LandLine | Cell | Fax,

  All = LandLine | Cell | Fax | Internet
}

...

Console.Write(NameToBits(PhoneService.All));
```

Output:

```
LandLine, Cell, Fax, Internet
```

You can implement `NameToBits` as a *extension* method, e.g.

```
public static class EnumsExtensions {
  public static string NameToBits<T>(this T value) where T : Enum {
    // If not marked with `Flags` return name without splitting into bits
    if (typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(FlagsAttribute)) == null)
      return Enum.GetName(typeof(T), value);

    IEnumerable<string> Names() {
      ulong data = Convert.ToUInt64(value);

      for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
        if ((data & (1ul << i)) != 0)
          yield return Enum.GetName(typeof(T), 1ul << i);
    }

    return string.Join(", ", Names());
  }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
Console.Write(PhoneService.All.NameToBits());
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8P7Los)

Comment: How to make this dynamic, by removing the hardcoded 64?

Comment: @Anoop: `enum` must be base on integer integral type (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) which can be `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, ..., `long`, `ulong`. To be on the safer side of the road, I've selected the largest one - `ulong`. Please, note, that `Int128` *can't* be used in `enum` declaration. Technically, you can put `8 * sizeof(long)` instead of `64` if you want.

Comment: shouldn't method be named `BitsToNames` (or `NamesFromBits`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a utility method to do that:

```
public List<PhoneService> GetSubFlags(PhoneService item)
{
    return Enum.GetValues<PhoneService>()
        .Where(ps => item.HasFlag(ps) && item != ps)
        .ToList();
}
```

and you can use it to print the values like this:

```
var subFlags = GetSubFlags(PhoneService.All);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", subFlags));
```

Comment: I have got `None, LandLine, Cell, Fax, Internet` as the result when I've run your code. Please, note that `None` should not be mentioned. Another (possible) problem if we have several *combinations*, e.g. `Offline = LandLine | Cell | Fax` which should not be mentioned

Comment: Side note: let the methods be `static` - you don't want `this` here